# Gnuplot: connecting two data with line at a certain point

Tags: gnuplot

I want a graph using gnuplot with two data in mixed scheme.

This is a data consisting of 3 columns:

```
x   y1   y2
1   0    1    
2   0    1    
3   0    1    
4   0    1    
5   0    1    
6   0    1    
7   0    1    
8   0    1    
9   0.1  1.2
10  0.1  1.23
```

What I want is that one line draws without seam.
e.g.

```
From x=1 to x=5, use y1 value, then from x=6 to x=10 use y2 value.
```

And, all the points are connected with one single line.

Does any body know how to make it with simple gnuplot command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prue `Gnuplot` soulution:

```
plot 'sheme.dat' u 1:($1<=5?$2:$3) w l
```

If you want, you can refine the condition to handle cases x<1 and x>10...

**OR**

If you want to plot *lines* 1-5 with y1 and 6-10 with y2, use column zero:

```
plot 'sheme.dat' u 1:($0<=4?$2:$3) w l
```

[image]

Comment: Oh! And 'comment out' the header of your data file with '#'!

Comment: Thank you so much! One more related question is there. If the data in 3rd column is separated to other file, say sheme2.dat, how can i draw a same graph with pure gnuplot commands?

Comment: No, there is no (prue `Gnuplot`) solution to merge columns of different files :-/

Comment: But there is a little trick just for your problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37839477/gnuplot-connecting-two-data-with-line-at-a-certain-point-from-different-data-fi/37839478#37839478

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there is no solution with pure gnuplot, but you can do almost everything by invoking an external  unix tool. If you remove the first line (header) in your data file (henceforth `data.txt`), this should work:

```
plot "<awk '{if (NR<=5) print $1,$2; else print $1,$3}' data.txt"  w lp
```

[image]