# Gnuplot: connecting two data with line at a certain point from different data files

Tags: gnuplot

This question is an extension [of a previously answered one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835244/gnuplot-connecting-two-data-with-line-at-a-certain-point/37836469?noredirect=1#comment63137160_37836469).

I want a graph using gnuplot with two data in mixed scheme. This is a data consisting of 3 columns:

```
#x   y1   y2
1   0    1    
2   0    1    
3   0    1    
4   0    1    
5   0    1    
6   0    1    
7   0    1    
8   0    1    
9   0.1  1.2
10  0.1  1.23
```

What I want is that one line draws without seam. e.g.

From x=1 to x=5, use y1 value, then from x=6 to x=10 use y2 value.

And, all the points are connected with one single line. Does any body know how to make it with simple gnuplot command?

**One more related question is there. If the data in 3rd column is separated to other file, say sheme2.dat, how can i draw a same graph with pure gnuplot commands?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you absolutely want to use pure `Gnuplot` you can cheat a little with variables(, but I suggest you to rethink the problem):

```
set term unknown

plot 'sheme.dat' u 1:2 every ::::4
x0=GPVAL_DATA_X_MAX
y0=GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX

plot 'sheme2.dat' u 1:2 every ::5
x1=GPVAL_DATA_X_MIN
y1=GPVAL_DATA_Y_MIN

set term wxt
# or png or qt or...

set arrow 1 from x0,y0 to x1,y1 nohead lc 1
plot 'sheme.dat' u 1:2 every ::::4 w l lc 1
replot 'sheme2.dat' u 1:2 every ::5 w l lc 1
```

This is a tricky way to connect the last and first data points with an arrow, but the conditions of this problem are so specific.

[image]

Comment: This works only when maximum of range [a,b] is at b and minimum of range [b,c] at b. In gnuplot 5, you can use `stats` to circumvent this problem.

Comment: Oh, sorry, the `every` is there for this, but shouldn't it be removed from the last 2 lines?

Comment: No, the every is also required in the last 2 lines. OR... you can replace it with `using 0:($0<=4?$2:1/0) and using 0:($0>4?$2:1/0)`

Answer (score 0):

For a file with columns 1/2 and a second file with column 3 you can use `paste` as well:

```
plot "<paste -d ' ' data1.dat data2.dat" using 1:($1<=5?$2:$3) with lines
```

With the `-d ' '` meaning that data1.dat and data2.dat will be separated by a single space.

For three columns in one file (as answered before)

```
plot "data.dat" using 1:($1<=5?$2:$3) with lines
```

Comment: No. As I mentioned at the first line this is not the original question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835244/gnuplot-connecting-two-data-with-line-at-a-certain-point/37836469?noredirect=1#comment63137160_37836469) you answered correctly but an extended one: the extended question (indicated bold in the last 2 lines) is to solve the problem from 2 files with 2-2 columns.

Comment: You're absolutely right, I should've read things more carefully! I edited my answer to account for the extended question.

Comment: Not bad :) You are right: the solution with an external paste is more simple than using only internal Gnuplot commands. Unfortunately, the OP wanted "**...with pure gnuplot commands**" : )